# ¿Por qué al imprimir en distintas aplicaciones, las impresiones son distintas en impresora ZEBRA Q360?

Tags: java, android-studio, impresión, zebra

Tengo dos aplicaciones una móvil en donde se desarrollo en android studio y la otra es de escritorio, al imprimir con la app móvil sale bien pero cuando se reinicia la impresora o se imprime en la de escritorio, la siguiente impresión de la app móvil sale distorsionada, adjunto el código de los textos a imprimir:

```
public void imprimirElementos(String codigo, String descripcion, double precio) {
        String codigoZPL = "^FO20,20^A0N,25,25^FB200,1,0,C^FWI^FH^FD" + codigo + "^FS";
        String descripcionZPL = "^FO275,30^A0N,32,32^FB300,2,0,L^CI28^CW1^FWI^FH^FD" + descripcion + "^FS";
        String precioZPL = "^FO175,130^A0N,40,40^FB400,1,0,L^FWI^FH^FDL.^FS" +
                "^FO150,100^A0N,90,90^FB350,1,0,L^FWI^FH^FD" + String.format("%.2f", precio) + "^FS";
        String codigoBarras = "^FO70,50^BY3.1,0.1^BCN,35,Y,N,N^FD^A^FH^FD^CI10^FD" + "^FS";
        String zplCommand = "^XA" + codigoZPL + descripcionZPL + precioZPL + codigoBarras + "^XZ";
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

Este leguaje es ZPL para las impresoras térmicas zebra.

Answer (score 0):

Suena muchísimo a que la impresora conserva cosas en caché y lo mantiene.

Siguiendo cosas como [esta](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2362606-zebra-printer-issues-with-clear-buffer-or-memory) podrías probar limpiar el buffer con `^JA` antes de comenzar la impresión.

Comment: Ese comando se ejecuta en el escritorio o tienes que implementarlo en el codigo anterior?, como veras no tengo mucha experiencia en impresoras termicas.

Comment: Tampoco lo he trabajado mucho pero, por como se ve en el código que compartes, posiblemente vaya dentro del zplCommand (todo el serializado), antes de todo lo demás, para que lo primero que haga sea limpiar el buffer, siempre.